# How can I store each key-value pair of my python dictionary on a separate line in json file?

Tags: python, json, dump

I am not sure if this question has been asked before but I could not find it.

I have a python dictionary where all values are a list. So, for example:

`d = {"car" : ["toyota", "honda"], "bus" : ["hackney", "bombardier"]`

When I try to dump this to a json file via:

```
with open(output.json, 'w') as f:
   json.dump(d, f)
```

I get:

```
{
   "car": [
      "toyota",
      "honda"
   ],
   "bus": [
      "hackney",
      "bombardier"
   ]
}
```

But I want it to look like:

```
{
   "car": [ "toyota", "honda"]
   "bus": [ "hackney", "bombardier"]
}
```

I tried with indent=2 and indent=4 but yet no luck! Any ideas? I ideally want to accomplish this without having to use any other packages.

Comment: You can't, unless you want to write your own JSON encoder...

Answer (score 0):

The only way that you can do this is by print it.